# Error installing haskelly to use with VSCode

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to install Haskelly so that I can use VSCode to build and debug Haskell. The issue here is that when I try to install intero, Quick Check and stack-run using the following command:

> stack install intero QuickCheck stack-run

I get the following error:

> Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions
>   were encountered:
>
> In the dependencies for stack-run-0.1.1.4:
>       conduit-1.3.1.1 from stack configuration does not match >1.1 && <1.3  (latest matching version is 1.2.13.1)
>       conduit-extra-1.3.4 from stack configuration does not match >=1.1 && <1.2  (latest matching version is 1.1.17) needed since stack-run is
>   a build target.
>
> Some different approaches to resolving this:
>
> - Set 'allow-newer: true' in C:\sr\config.yaml to ignore all version
>     constraints and build anyway.
> - Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in
>     C:\sr\global-project\stack.yaml:
>
>   - conduit-1.2.13.1@sha256:afd4db7fe66ae7af3d418e1a932384a8dee08df2f6299cca80e53ba964ce1228,4371
>   - conduit-extra-1.1.17@sha256:dfa0d00dc11a8a4c3fdff15374c378ee34c25a2255b52194aa1ea3c1f1a63fd7,4521
>
> Plan construction failed.

Now while it does provide some clues as to what I'm supposed to do, I have no clue what it means to add these things to stack.yaml. I found stack.yaml, and it's just a file that I seemingly can't open or modify. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Noting that this was also asked at https://old.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/dnxpcs/trouble_installing_haskelly/ (although I think this is okay since Reddit isn't an SE site).

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem installing `stack-run`, documented here: https://github.com/yamadapc/stack-run/issues/21.

I solved it by adding the following to my `stack.yaml`:

```
extra-deps:
    - url: https://github.com/Magicloud/stack-run/archive/master.zip
```